# iPad suddenly shows "Hello" screen and asks for activation

Tags: ipad, apple-id, activation-lock

I left my work iPad (7th gen) with the screen off for a few hours, came back to it and it was suddenly showing a "Hello" screen.

I have to select a language, country and network and it offers a "Quick Start". I then press "set up manually" and it says it's activating the iPad.

It then requires a login on an "Activation Lock" using the Apple ID the iPad was set up with. I don't know the password as it's my IT department's Apple ID.

Why has this suddenly happened? When IT enter the password when I return to work in the new year, will the iPad be back to normal or will it need setting up again?

The "Hello" screen implies the iPad needs activating from scratch, implying it's been reset to its factory state. Is this the case?

Thanks.

Comment: "When IT enter the password..." Is this iPad a managed device through your work?  If so, could a certificate expired (end of the year) or something or your IT department did a remote reset?

Comment: It's a work iPad but I don't think they 'manage' it enough to do a remote reset, as they seemed a bit relaxed about setting it up and even suggested I created a new Apple ID to log into the App Store.

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason for the iPad to enter the setup screen on its own.  However, I do know that MDM systems can trigger such activity remotely.  I don't know if this is what happened to your iPad but the info so far is pointing to that.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the iPad's settings beforehand that suggests it could be controlled remotely but it seems it's possible from what you've said.

 Do you think the setup screen coming on means the iPad's been totally reset to its default state? 

The only other thing that was out of the ordinary was that a system update notification popped up not long before this happened and I postponed it. I don't know if that's linked or not.